# Firebase Update Function cant be used

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im just learning to use `firebase`, but I cannot update the data,
I think the `id` is not passed to `devRef.update` in `putData` function because in `VSCode` its still a black color.

How can I send `id` as key for update a data?

Please help me, sorry for my poor English, thanks before

```
btnPut.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     putData(id, formName.value, formBadge.value, formPosition.value);

     e.preventDefault();
});

function putData(id, formName, formBadge, formPosition) {
    devRef.update({
        id: {
            name: formName,
            badge: formBadge,
            position: formPosition
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Here for image]

Comment: What isn't working about this code?

Comment: its need to use brackets so the id will look like this [id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make `id` the name of the key to update, you should use this JavaScript syntax:

```
    devRef.update({
        [id]: {
            name: formName,
            badge: formBadge,
            position: formPosition
        }
    });
```

Note the square brackets around `id`.

Comment: Its work like as i want, thank you so much, have a nice day :D